# Variable isn't considered as object when called by Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I have a poll and when user click on one of the options, it sends data through ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/poll.php',
    data: {option: option, IDpoll: IDpoll},
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.msg == "0") {
            $( "#pollArea" ).load( "/pollVote.php", { allow: true }, function() {
                  alert( "Ďakujeme za Váš hlas!" );
                });
        }
        else {
            alert(data.msg);
            alert("V tejto ankete ste už hlasovali.");}
        }
    });
```

This works fine. Now data are passed to the file poll.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['option']) && isset($_POST['IDpoll'])) {
    require 'includes/config.inc.php';
    $ip     = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $option = $pdo->quote($_POST['option']);
    $IDpoll = $pdo->quote($_POST['IDpoll']);
    $date   = date("d.m.Y H:i:s");
    $poll   = new Poll();
    $msg    = $poll->votePoll($IDpoll, $ip, $option, $date);
    $arr    = array(
        'msg' => $msg

    );
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This also works, the problem happened in class Poll - method VotePoll:

```
public function votePoll($IDpoll, $ip, $option, $date)
    {
        try {
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `IDpoll` = '$IDpoll' AND `ip` = '$ip'";
        $result = $this->pdo->query($query);    
        if ($result->rowCount() == 0) {
           /* do stuff */
      }
      catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
      }
    }
```

And the error message from the ajax call is following: **Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object**. I know what this message means, but I can't find out why the variable $result isn't considered as PDO object. Strange thing is, that when I try to call function votePoll manually, it works perfectly and when I use var_dump on result it is PDO object. So where is the mistake?

EDIT: I forgot to say I was just editing this function. Originally it worked with mysqli but I wanted to switch to pdo (so query and stuff like that are okay).

Comment: perhaps not important, but there is a syntax error in your votePoll function: the if is NOT closed properly, unless you didn't copy it correctly..! http://prntscr.com/4go8mq . In any case, it seems that the query is failing. Maybe there is something wrong there? if $result is **not** an object, then the query is probably **not** returning anything.

Comment: Yes I copied it wrong, the bracket isn't missing (this kind of error would my IDE display). I am sure query is okay, because as I said, when I tried called that function manually, it works and $result was object.

Comment: Then have you tried checking if both $IDPoll and $option are **really being retrieved correctly?** try logging them back.

Comment: You are right. I have it. Gonna write the solution, thanks.

Comment: Along with briosheje, I would check your query, to make sure that `IDpoll` is being included in the string correctly. is `IDPoll` a string when you send it? (Side note: I usually use prepared statements in PHP anytime I am inserting data into the DB that could have possibly been touched by a user, either in the client UI or just by manually creating/modifying requests)

Comment: Glad you solved it :P most of the times, if a PDO object is **not** an object, the problem is in the query itself. If it works manually, then the problem must be in the variables you're inserting there.. And there you are! ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, this problem was in these lines:

```
   $option = $pdo->quote($_POST['option']);
   $IDpoll = $pdo->quote($_POST['IDpoll']);
```

PDO quote function add quotes to the string so option became 'option' etc. Then it was sent to query where additional quotes were added, so the result was ''option'' and that is error.

Comment: Wouldn't `quote()` add escaped quotes, so instead of inserting `''option''` it would be inserting `'\'option\''`, which is valid (if not exactly desired behavior)?